# Как передать аргумент с данными в onClick для Button?

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

Использую React+redux(храню состояние в хранилищах).

Использую `Button` (аналог обычной кнопки) из [material-ui](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#button)

Фрагмент компонента:

```
<Button variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={saveSelectedProject} className={classes.button}>Скачать</Button>
```

сама функция `saveSelectedProject` располагается в редьюсере и выглядит вот так:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    saveSelectedProject: () => {
    dispatch(actions.saveSelectedProject(items));
  },
});
```

Как из компонента передать массив `items` в редьюсер?

Или иначе, как в `mapDispatchToProps` получить доступ к `items` в компоненте по нажатии кнопки?

Comment: `распологается в редьюсере` - вы ничего не перепутали? Может быть в контейнере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в компоненте без состояния создать функцию второго порядка(принимающую на вход параметры и возвращающая другую функцию), то есть вот так:

```
const onClick = (items, activeButtonChange) => () => {
  console.log(`items ${items[0].name}`);
  console.log(`activeButtonChange ${activeButtonChange}`);
};

<Button variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={onClick(items, saveSelectedProject)} className={classes.button}>Скачать</Button>
```

Или второй вариант, более правильный, это

```
<Button variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={saveSelectedProject(selectedItems)} className={classes.button}>Скачать</Button>
```

и в редьюсере:

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({    
      saveSelectedProject: item => () => {
        console.log(`item ${item.label}`);
        dispatch(actions.saveSelectedProject(item));
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={this.props.saveSelectedProject(selectedItems)} className={classes.button}>Скачать</Button>


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({    
  saveSelectedProject: (item) => {
    console.log(`item ${item.label}`);
    dispatch(actions.saveSelectedProject(item));
  },
  ...
})
```